# How to fix app (using coredata) freeze issue on iOS12

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, freeze, magicalrecord

I have been working in an app. Its using core data and magical record library. And it was working fine in iOS 11.

But in iOS 12 the app is randomly getting freeze and its not only freeze but a deadlock. In order to use the app again the only way is to kill and run again.

whenever I am debugging and it freeze I pause the thread to check which method is currently executing. Every time its related to coredata. Sometimes it stuck on executeFetchRequest method. Sometimes while saving data in local db.

I think there are some other developers as well who are facing the same issue For reference :- https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/1331

I have tried some solutions for it like :-

• Instead of using default context using privateQueueContext and setting its parent the default context.
• Tried performBlockAndWait as suggested in some threads. 
But I am not able to fix it. Reason for asking this question here is only to have the vision clear which way to proceed.

Thanks,

Comment: Try enabling `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` and see if that helps you figure out if there is a multi-threading violation occurring.  https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/  can help you with how to do that.

Comment: I tired using the link you provided and added Arguments passed on launch.
And run the app , it crashes. And yes the log says CoreData: annotation: Core Data multi-threading assertions enabled. But don't know what else to do?

Comment: There should be some console logging describing the violation and you can get stack traces to figure out where you are and what you're doing wrong.

Comment: You're going to need to read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background carefully to understand the restrictions on using Core Data in a multithreaded scenario and figure out where you are violating those restrictions (since that seems to be what is going on).

Comment: *some console logging* So you mean in release mode? 
Because in debug mode app will crash on start?

Comment: With that flag turned on it should drop into the debugger at __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__ (see the blog post I linked to) and the call you're making that violates the multithreading rules should be in the call chain.

Comment: If you do some searching on that flag name you'll find some useful tips:  https://pawanpoudel.svbtle.com/fixing-core-data-concurrency-violations  The blog post it has a bad link to is here:  https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/   Some of this could be old though.

Comment: Note this other freeze post with a solution found (wrong data type): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236860/app-freeze-on-coredata-save?rq=1

Comment: This one also has some very good information and a link to a blog post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666725/ios-coredata-with-3-moc-solution-app-freezes-on-saving-process?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am having a look at these.